Open a new instance of notepad++
I have an existing instance of Notepad++ open with some files that I typically want to keep open.
I also have a new code project that I would like to open with Notepad++'s "Open Folder as workspace" option.
Looking to just open a second clean Notepad++ instance, so I can open up my code project in the second window.

Figured out the answer while I was writing the question.  Run this in powershell:
PS> Start-Process notepad++ -ArgumentList "-multiInst -nosession"

Please note, this window will not reopen if you close notepad++ like the "default session" does.  Also note, if you run powershell as administrator, then notepad++ will also open in administrator mode
